# Revision of form creates new document with new title, looking to auto-delete original document

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, list-form, infopath-rules

We have an InfoPath 2010 form published on SharePoint 2013 which faculty uses at the end of year to submit budget forms. Once the form is populated and submitted the template creates a title affixing the submitters name behind the G/L number. When the admin assistant processes the forms often times she must update/create a new G/L. In doing so a new document is created with the new G/L and submitter. She is looking for a way to automatically delete or overwrite the original document once it has been edited.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I usually handle this by creating a "fileName" field that is created either as a rule on form load or as a rule on submit.  This creates a unique file name for your form, and allows it to overwrite previously saved forms on submit.

The rule will be an "Action" rule that sets a fields value.  Set the field's value to something uniqe.  If the G/L is unique, that might work.  I usually use a date and the submitter's ID, but anything unique will work.

In the rule, include a condition that checks to see if the filename field already is blank.  If so, run the rule.

Last, you need to use the the new field as the file name in your submit data connection.  And check the box "Allow overwrite if file exists".  This will allow it to overwrite the existing file of the same file name.